# Escape single quote ( ' ) in jquery.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the code below to send some data through a function "populate", arguments may contain single quotes or double quotes inside. now please help me out here..

```
.attr('onclick', "populate('" + res.data[i].title + "','" + res.data[i].content + "','" + res.data[i].id + "')")
```

Comment: Please don't use Javascript to attach an attribute to attach an event handler. Use the JS to add the event directly to the element you already have a reference to.

Comment: Have you tried assigning instead. `addEventListener("onclick", populate.bind(tihs, args))` or `$(selector).on("click", function(){populate(args)})`

Comment: I would prefer to have the populate function take up res.data[i] instead of taking title, content and id. Inside the populate function you can fetch them from the object.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is this:

```
.attr('onclick', function() {
    populate(res.data[i].title, res.data[i].content, res.data[i].id)
})
```

Comment: actually the way I applied is working well... only the problem occurs when text representing the variable itself contain single quotes,,.